# Show that there exists no integer coordinates on curve

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

**Problem:** Show that there does not exist any integer coordinates to the curve
$$y = \frac{x^2-3}{4}, x\in \mathbb{R}.$$

**My attempt:** The problem is equivalent of saying that there does not exist any $x\in \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$x^2-3 \equiv 0 \text{ mod } 4.$$

I've tried to factor $x^2-3 \equiv (x+\sqrt{3})(x-\sqrt{3}) \text{ mod } 4$ and reason that this implies that 
$$ x+\sqrt{3} \text{ mod } 4$$
or 
$$ x-\sqrt{3} \text{ mod } 4.$$
This would then mean that $x = \pm \sqrt{3} + 4l, l \in \mathbb{Z}$, which is not an integer. I don't think such a solution would be valid though for example for $x = \sqrt{3}$ on of the factors $x \pm \sqrt{3}$ wouldn't be an integer. Would appreciate any insight on this problem.

Comment: Hint: what are the only squares $\pmod 4$?

Comment: you wrote $\sqrt{3}$, and you were thinking 1.73..., but that doesn't make sense here. So...what does $\sqrt{3}$ really mean in this case? (Hint: if you didn't know the decimal expansion for $\sqrt{3}\in\mathbb{R}$, how would you describe it?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem gives you a chance to review basic modulo arithmetic with the squares. So any integer can be either odd or even. Hence you can write: For any $x \in \mathbb{Z}$, $x = 2k$ or $x = 2k + 1$.

Thus: $x^2 = (2k)^2 = 4k^2 \equiv 0 \pmod 4$ or $x^2 = (2k + 1)^2 = 4(k^2 + k) + 1 \equiv 1\pmod 4$.

But your equation gives: $x^2 \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ and this can't happen. So the answer follows.

Answer (score 2):

LAcarguy's answer is very succinct and correct, so rather than repeat it, let me focus on where your own solution is flawed.

You have:

> I've tried to factor $x^2-3 \equiv (x+\sqrt{3})(x-\sqrt{3}) \text{ mod } 4$ and reason that this implies that 
>   $$ x+\sqrt{3} \text{ mod } 4$$
>   or 
>   $$ x-\sqrt{3} \text{ mod } 4.$$

Nope!  First of all, you seem to be trying to generalize the "zero product property" (if $ab=0$ then either $a=0$ or $b=0$) to the case of modular arithmetic.  But it isn't the case that if $ab \equiv 0 \mod{4}$ then $a \equiv 0$ mod 4  or $b \equiv 0$ mod 4.  (Consider what happens if both $a$ and $b$ are $\equiv 2$ mod 4.)  In fact the zero-product property only holds in modular arithmetic when you are working mod $p$ for some *prime* number -- if you are working modulo a composite number it fails.

The second issue has to do with how you factored that polynomial.  Factorization in modular arithmetic can behave in unexpected ways.  This is a bit harder to explain, so let me give you a different example.  Suppose you are working modulo 11, and you want to factor $x^2-5$.  Your instincts are probably to factor it as $(x-\sqrt{5})(x+\sqrt{5})$, which would be correct if we were factoring over $\mathbb{R}$.  But over the integers mod 11, we have $x^2-5 \equiv (x-4)(x+4)$ (don't take my word for it, multiply it out and see!). So the equation $x^2 \equiv 5 \mod{11}$ has two solutions:  $x \equiv 4$ and $x \equiv -4 \equiv 7$.  No need to mess around with irrational numbers at all.

As a general rule, if you are working over the integers, and looking for integer solutions, don't try to factor over the reals -- it will just lead you astray.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks!